# Preventing form submission with invalid fields

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, alert

I have been trying to make a simple HTML form that takes a phone number, password, and confirmed password. I tried using the HTML5 required attribute to ensure all fields were filled out upon submission, but since finding out Safari doesn't support that, I moved on to using the following code from a different stack overflow topic to validate the form:

```
var form = document.getElementById('text'); // form has to have ID: <form id="formID">
    form.noValidate = true;
    form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) { // listen for form submitting
        if (!event.target.checkValidity()) {
            event.preventDefault(); // dismiss the default functionality
            if (document.getElementById('password_confirm').value != document.getElementById('password').value) {
                alert('Passwords must match');
                //document.getElementById("alert_pw_match").style.color = rgba(37, 33, 90, 0.64);
            } else {
                // input is valid -- reset the error message
                alert('All fields are required');
            }
        }
    }, false);
```

The issue I'm having is that I want to move away from using the standard alert boxes and just highlight the relevant fields or display some text indicating why the form is invalid, but whenever I add a line other than the alert the form submits without anything happening.

Comment: use return false;

Comment: I tried that earlier and it didn't work